# why LG android tablet incompatible with api level min 9

Tags: android, api, lg

I tried to test an app with LG android version 4.4.2, kernel version 3.4.0. My app has following in build.gradle:-

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.androidbegin.dialogfragmenttutorial"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
 }

   dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
 }
```

What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: `make minSdkVersion 11`

Comment: propably you have wrong drivers (or maybe custom Android or problem with ADB), Device Chooser shows API in ver. 1 on your LG and offline device. even if device isn't supported (e.g. minSdk set to 14 and device with 10) it should be listed as online

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it, but when I had this exact problem with this exact phone, I moved my USB jack to a different outlet.  Worked for me.  I'm running Android Studio on a 2015 Macbook Pro